# how to make a movie with 30 frames c#, opencvsharp

Tags: c#, opencv, video, camera

I want to make a movie with 30 frames.

Take one minute with cam and watch video, video length is only 42 seconds.

As a result of measuring the time, it is output as 21 frames.

How can I make a 30 frame video?

Below is a description of the running time.

```
....

00:00:01.0339097
00:00:01.0788484
00:00:01.1256316
00:00:01.1741762
00:00:01.2210662
00:00:01.2660053
00:00:01.3138742
00:00:01.3605831
00:00:01.4084542
00:00:01.4543680
00:00:01.5004309
00:00:01.5492773
00:00:01.5951540
00:00:01.6420466
00:00:01.6899155
00:00:01.7348539
00:00:01.7827228
00:00:01.8282291
00:00:01.8760989
00:00:01.9239678
00:00:01.9718930
....
```

Below is the source code.

```
    private void StartTimer()
    {
        if (writer == null)
        {
            Utilitys.TStimeD = DateTime.Now;
            TStimeS = Utilitys.TStimeD.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            aviPath = TStimeS + ".avi";
            writer = Cv.CreateVideoWriter(aviPath, "XVID", 30, new CvSize(640, 240));
        }
        timer1.Interval = 33;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (_captureInProgress)
        {
            _image = _capture.QueryFrame();
            try { 

                writer.WriteFrame(_image);
                Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - Utilitys.TStimeD).ToString());
                //Cv.ReleaseImage(_image);
            }
            catch(System.AccessViolationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("System.AccessViolationException");
            }catch(System.ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                Console.Write("System.ObjectDisposedException");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a timer for this, because even if it was called 30 times per second absolutely precisely, there would be no time left for the image grabbing and consuming/displaying.

I would implement the throttling myself.

```
    async void GrabImages(CancellationToken ct, int FPS)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        var imageSlotInMS = 1000.0 / FPS;

        for (ulong grabbed = 0; !ct.IsCancellationRequested;)
        {
            var expectedTimePosInMS = grabbed * imageSlotInMS;

            var time2WaitInMS = expectedTimePosInMS - sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            if (time2WaitInMS > 0)
                await Task.Delay((int)time2WaitInMS);

            var image = await GrabImage();
            DisplayImage(image);
            grabbed++;
        }

        sw.Stop();
    }
```

In the worst case you will at least be running at the maximally possible FPS, if the performance of the system doesn't permit the desired one.

Another advantage of this approach approach is that you can perform image grabbing on a different thread which will free the primary (UI) thread from this duty and make it behave smoother.